# Matlab gui returns output arguments too soon

Tags: matlab, user-interface, output

Although I'm a fairly moderate matlabber, I can't get my gui to work. It's intended to be used for me to have a one-click way of organizing my downloads, but it returns the output arguments way too soon.
The code is as follows:

```
function [answer]=makegui(files,season,episode)
close all
%% Initialize variables
% Input (if empty)
if nargin==0
    files{1}='Avengers';
    files{2}='NCIS';
    files{3}='Would I Lie to You';
    season{1}=1;
    season{2}=2;
    season{3}=3;
    episode{1}=11;
    episode{2}=22;
    episode{3}=24;
else
    if length(files)>length(season) || length(files)>length(episode)
        sprintf('Not enough filenames provided')
        delete(fig)
    end
end

width=450;
height=100+25*length(files);

% Function variables
checks=ones(1,length(files));

% Output variables
answer=[];
fig = figure('Name','Fili3','NumberTitle','off','Visible','off','Position',[360,500,width,height],'CloseRequestFcn',@temp); % Create figure

%% Declare buttons
all    = uicontrol('Style','checkbox',...
    'String','Select all','Position',[50,height-35,70,25],...
    'Callback',{@all_Callback},'Value',1);

for i=1:length(files)
    item{i}=uicontrol('Style','checkbox',...
        'String',files{i},'Position',[75,height-60-25*i,150,25],...
        'Callback',@item_Callback,'Value',1);
    uicontrol('Style','text','String',sprintf('%d',season{i}),...
        'Position',[320,height-60-25*i,25,25]);
    uicontrol('Style','text','String',sprintf('%d',episode{i}),...
        'Position',[370,height-60-25*i,25,25]);
end
uicontrol('Style','text','String','TV Show Name',...
    'Position',[90,height-60,60,15]);
uicontrol('Style','text','String','Season',...
    'Position',[300,height-60,60,15]);
uicontrol('Style','text','String','Episode',...
    'Position',[350,height-60,60,15]);
options = uicontrol('Style','popupmenu',...
    'String',{'Rename and Move','Rename','Move'},...
    'Position',[300,height-35,120,25],...
    'Value',1);
uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','String','Run',...
    'Position',[345,12,30,30],'Callback',@closefunction);

% Make UI visible
fig.Visible='on';
movegui(fig,'center')

%% Callback functions

    function all_Callback(source,eventdata)
        if source.Value
            checks=ones(1,length(files));
        else
            checks=zeros(1,length(files));
        end
        source.Value
        for j=1:length(files)
            item{j}.Value=source.Value;
        end
    end

    function item_Callback(source,eventdata)
        S=regexp(files,source.String);
        i=find(~cellfun(@isempty,S));
        checks(i)=source.Value;
        if source.Value==0
            all.Value=0;
        elseif source.Value==1 && sum(checks)==length(files)
            all.Value=1;
        end
    end

    function closefunction(source,eventdata)
        answer.checks=checks(:);
        answer.mode=options.Value;

        delete(fig)
    end

    function temp(source,eventdata)
        delete(fig)
    end
end
```

I added the nargin part to not constantly have to provide input arguments while testing, and later I intend to let the run button and the close function point to the same class. I want it to return answer, but if you run this on your own computer you'll see that it returns it as soon as answer is initialized, and then refuses to do anything else.

It's probably just a small snippet of code I'm forgetting but if someone could point me in the right direction that'd be great!

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: The GUI figure get close when it return the output? Or it stay active? I think that the problem is `answer=[]`, that called without any of the GUI functions, so it just give it back as an output and the main function is done... Anyway this line doesn't give you anything, try to delete it.

Comment: Don't I need to initialize the answer variable? Otherwise the callback functions won't communicate properly. And it returns [1] [1] [1] [1], not just []...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Just needed to add waitfor(fig).